# Searching for a collaborator for a physics simulation of multi-party elections

Tags: soft-question, simulations

I have completed a series of physics simulations on Matlab to find the equilibrium positions of parties in 2-D or 3-D voting space and compared them to the optimal positions that would provide the maximum average voter satisfaction. The physics aspects are in the use of forces that attract parties to voters.

Would anyone suggest a physicist or other academician who would be interested in providing guidance and contributing to a paper? Some leading authors on sociophysics have turned me down because multi-party politics is a field dominated by political scientists, but I think this simulation would be something novel.

Comment: Charitably this is a make-a-list questions, alternately it is simply off-topic as it is not about physics but about physicists. On a side note may I suggest that you are trying to write a simulation on [no-physics-subject] using *methods from* physics rather than using physics which would be pretty silly: *"as you can see neuron 184362642597829 in the brain of subject 74521 fires at time 89752.3617 seconds resulting in ..."*